# insert_row or append_row with Gspread python

Tags: python, gspread

When I run my script insert_row and append_row are putting each letter of the string into a new column.

Trying to insert an id '877' for example.

Didn't like integers

```
worksheet.append_row(877)
```

Returns

> *** TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tried wrapping this in the str() and it creates a new column for each letter.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: You want each letter in a different column?

Answer (score 4):

Strings have lenght (number of characters); integers don't. If you want to achieve a similar result, do this:

```
worksheet.append_row('877')
```

But in case you want the id in only one column, pass it as a list of one element:

```
worksheet.append_row([877])
```

EDIT:

worksheet.append_row gets an iterable element, and saves it in as many rows as it needs to iterate through it. e.g. [1,2,3,'asd'] will write four columns, one with each value. When you pass as a string, since strings are iterable, it saves each character in a separate column.