# Why does python say there are 4 arguments when there are only 3?

Tags: python, tkinter, gspread

I'm writing a Tkinter with gspread app. I believe the connections to the spreadsheets are made properly because i can read data off it. I'm using python 2.7.15 and gspread 0.6.2. I get the error. If i leave out the 'RAW' argument at the end of the function call, I no longer get any errors, but nothing gets written to the spreadsheet.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "app.py", line 22, in clicked
    sheet.insert_row(insertRow,index,'RAW')
TypeError: insert_row() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

---

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from Tkinter import *

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("client_secret.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("This").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet

#data = sheet.get_all_records()  # Get a list of all records

#row = sheet.row_values(3)  # Get a specific row
#col = sheet.col_values(3)  # Get a specific column
#cell = sheet.cell(1,2).value  # Get the value of a specific cell
def clicked():
    index = sheet.row_count
    index+=1
    insertRow = [nametxt.get(),placetxt.get(), phonetxt.get()]
    sheet.insert_row(insertRow,index,'RAW')
window = Tk()
window.title("Registration application")
window.geometry('700x700')
namelbl = Label(window, text="Name",font=("Ubuntu",20))
placelbl = Label(window, text="Place", font=("Ubuntu",20))
phonelbl = Label(window,text="Phone No", font=("Ubuntu",20))
placetxt = Entry(window,width = 20)
nametxt = Entry(window,width=20)
phonetxt = Entry(window,width = 20)
namelbl.grid(column=1, row=1,)
nametxt.grid(column=2, row=1)
placelbl.grid(column=1, row=2)
placetxt.grid(column=2,row=2)
phonelbl.grid(column =1, row=3)
phonetxt.grid(column = 2,row=3)
button = Button(window, text="submit",command=clicked)
button.grid(column=2, row=5)
window.mainloop()

#sheet.update_cell(2,2, "CHANGED")  # Update one cell
```

Comment: `sheet` is one of the arguments (its implicitly given as the first argument). Double check the documention of that method to see what arguments you should be giving it.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet), it's not clear what the problem here is. `Worksheet.insert_row` is defined with 3 parameters.

Comment: Maybe it's an outdated installed library? Try updating gspread.

Comment: Try `sheet.insert_row(insertRow, index, value_input_option='RAW')`.

Comment: @acw1668 that just gives me an error saying value_input_option is an undefined identifier

Comment: @Carcigenicate I know this is an old version of gspread, but that's because thenew version has a bug. It doesn't always connect to the spreadsheet. Shows an authentication error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258566/gspread-authentication-throwing-insufficient-permission?rq=1 only the third answer solved that problem for me

Comment: And is the down vote really necessary, people?

Comment: @ArunParolikkal: From the [source `0.6.2`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/v0.6.2/gspread/models.py#634): `def insert_row(self, values, index=1):`. Therefore you have to use: `sheet.insert_row(insertRow, index)`

Comment: @ArunParolikkal: Relevant [append-row-with-gspread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248734/insert-row-or-append-row-with-gspread-python)

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of gspread. In the version you're using the definition of `insert_row` looks like this:

```
def insert_row(self, values, index=1):
```

Notice how it takes only three arguments: `self` (automatically passed when called on an instance), along with `values` and `index`. It doesn't accept any other parameters. You need to remove the `RAW` argument for your code to work with this version of the library.

Comment: This gets rid if the error but doesn't add columns in the spreadsheet. the spreadsheet does say,though that an edit was made a few seconds ago by anonymous